# Use utf-8 encoding instead of iso-8859-1

Tags: tex4ht, input-encodings, htlatex

I am using htlatex to generate an html file.  I use some special characters like é and å in the document.

These characters come out looking fine when I open the resulting html file in Safari.  However, they don't display properly when the html is served from Github.

Looking at the html, I see this line in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1">
```

If I replace it with this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

everything works correctly.

I have tried using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in the .tex file, but it makes no difference.

Is there a way to force `charset=UTF-8`, or will I just have to do this manually each time I update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell `tex4ht` to use `utf-8` encoding. It is a little bit complicated using `htlatex`:

```
htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8" " -cmozhtf -utf8"
```

It is easier to require it using `make4ht`

```
make4ht -u filename.tex
```