# htlatex combining multiple command line options

Tags: htlatex

I use htlatex to generate an html file with this command:

```
htlatex filename.tex "html,1,sections+"
```

I ran into a problem where the output used iso-88859-1 instead of utf-8, which was solved:  [Use utf-8 encoding instead of iso-8859-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423723/use-utf-8-encoding-instead-of-iso-8859-1)

The solution was to run the command with these arguments:

```
htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8" "-cmozhtf -utf8"
```

Which makes the encoding come out correctly.  However, I now can't seem to incorporate all of the command line options that I need.  (I.e., 1 and sections+ with the utf-8 related options).

I tried shooting in the dark with a few variations:

```
# encoding ends up wrong:
htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8,1,sections+" "-cmozhtf -utf8"
# sectioning ends up broken:
htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,1,sections+,charset=utf-8" "-cmozhtf -utf8"
```

Obviously I'm just shooting in the dark here.  I checked documentation here:  https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html#QQ1-9-34.  The syntax is supposed to be:

```
htlatex filename "options1" "option2" "options3" "options4"
```

I assume the issue is that I'm not ordering the "options1" portion correctly, but I'm not sure and I can't find more informative documentation.  I'm looking for either the correct syntax or documentation that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why it is better to use `make4ht` instead of `htlatex`. I forgot that it is necessary to add space before " -cmozhtf -utf8", otherwise the first option is ignored and you will get wrong encoding, because wrong conversion table will be used. I don't think there should be any difference regarding output of `"xhtml,charset=utf-8,1,sections+"` and  `"xhtml,1,sections+,charset=utf-8"`, both versions are correct. Only the first option is important, order of the rest doesn't matter.

So correct call to `htlatex` is:

```
 htlatex sample "xhtml,1,sections+,charset=utf-8" " -cmozhtf -utf8"
```

It is simpler using `make4ht`:

```
make4ht -u sample.tex "1,sections+"
```

Comment: Thanks!  The command appears to work.  I have been struggling to install make4ht without success so far.  https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/issues/11